# converting data frame to ppp object using spatstat package

Tags: r, spatstat

I have a data frame

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(seq(1:10), 10), y = rep(seq(1:10), each = 10), diameter = rnorm(100, 0.3, 0.03), height = rnorm(100, 0.2, 001))
```

that I want to convert to the `ppp`file by means of the `ppp` of `spatstat` package. I want that the `diameter` and `height` variables are `marks` and I can not do this. I tried f.ex this

```
pp1<-ppp(df$x, df$y,  marks = data.frame(df %>% select(diameter, height)))
```

but does not work.

The output I want to have is similar to the data file `finepines` that is attached to the `spatstat` package

```
> finpines
Marked planar point pattern: 126 points
Mark variables: diameter, height 
window: rectangle = [-5, 5] x [-8, 2] metres
```

Comment: Please elaborate a little more on your statement "but does not work". Thank you.

Comment: The warning message described in my answer has been a topic here before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025517/point-patterns-in-spatstat#comment26367832_18025517

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define the observation window before you can define a planar point pattern `ppp` since we need to know both where points were observed and where there were no points. E.g. the intensity of the process is the average number of points per area so we need to know the area of the study region.

In your example I will assume the study region (observation window) is [0, 11] x [0, 11]. Then you can do:

```
library(spatstat)
df <- data.frame(x = rep(seq(1:10), 10),
                 y = rep(seq(1:10), each = 10),
                 diameter = rnorm(100, 0.3, 0.03),
                 height = rnorm(100, 0.2, 001))
W <- owin( c(0, 11), c(0,11) )
pp1 <- as.ppp( df, W = W)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, but I cannot judge whether you can accept this warning:

> Warning message:
>   In ppp(df$x, df$y, marks = data.frame(df %>% select(diameter, height))) :
>     99 points were rejected as lying outside the specified window

```
library(spatstat)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x = rep(seq(1:10), 10), y = rep(seq(1:10), each = 10), diameter = rnorm(100, 0.3, 0.03), height = rnorm(100, 0.2, 001))
pp1<-ppp(df$x, df$y,  marks = data.frame(df %>% select(diameter, height)))
```

The output is:

```
> pp1
Marked planar point pattern: 1 point
Mark variables: diameter, height 
window: rectangle = [0, 1] x [0, 1] units
*** 99 illegal points stored in attr(,“rejects”) ***
```